# Why does this regex match nothing? (using RegExr site)

Tags: regex

**Update**: I am using [this engine](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) to evaluate my tests

I have highlighted the matches:

[regex](http://regexr.com?2vr5s) **A***
string: BB AA AA BAA
result: BB AA AA BAA (no match)

[regex](http://regexr.com?2vr5v) **A***
string: AA AA BAA
result: `AA` AA BAA

[regex](http://regexr.com?2vr62) **A+**
string: BB AA AA BAA
result: BB `AA` `AA` B`AA`

I am wondering why in the first example, no `AA` is matched. and why in the second example, only the first `AA` is matched?

Comment: By chance are you trying to match `^A*` (but exempting the `^`?) Any flags you're applying?

Comment: What language is this used with?

Comment: What kind of regular expression is this?

Comment: What is the reguar expression engine that you are using? They do slightly differ.

Comment: What are you using to test the regex?  When I tried it, it worked [fine](http://regexpal.com/?flags=&regex=A*&input=BB%20AA%20AA%20BAA).

Comment: What programming language/regex flavor? How do you know there's "no match?" How about showing us some actual code?

Comment: What regex engine are you use? - Seems like a bug or something?. EDIT: wow 7 people asking the same thing within a minute.. lol

Comment: Not sure if it has mentioned before... but what language is this?

Comment: I am using this: http://regexr.com?2vr62

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really seems like a bug on regexr site.. Using regexbuddy I do see it captures all AA sequences by placing A*.. - What's more, if you test against BA* you'll see it correctly captures the last part of the string (BAA) - So this leads me to believe the engine is bugged and simply doesn't work with a single char + * token.

EDIT: if you watch closely, you'll notice that with the "global" flag on (so to match all sequences), regxr makes the `A*` sequence red: indicating it can't proces it correctly. (It probably wants to match an infinite times a 0-length string).

Answer (score 1):

You are matching `A*` which means 0 or more A's. Now you're getting match in all 3 cases like this:

1. Matches 0 length string at the sate of the string `^` and stops since 1st char in string is B
2. Matches `AA` and stops because 3rd char is a space
3. Matches all occurrences of 1 or more A's correctly.

Bottom Line: Use `A+` to match A's grouped together instead of `A*`.

Comment: Why `A*` stops after first match, but `A+` doesnt?

Comment: `A*` stops after the first match (of nothing). `A+` cannot match until it finds at least one `A`, but it does stop after greedily finishing the pattern.

Comment: Thanks @Phrogz for answering what I was also going to write. A* stops after successfully matching nothing but A+ has to find 1 A atleast.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are comparing the full string with your regex and `A*` only accepts 0 or any number of As, like `A`, `AA`, or `AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA`. As it starts with a `B`, your sentence doesn't match.

In the second case only the first `AA` is matched because you hava a space after them, and your regex doesn't accept it so the selection stops after the last A encountered.